# First steps in PDSOE: how to get correct view of window in ABL UI Designer perspective

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I started recently working with Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge, more known as PDSOE.

In order to see the windows I've created until now, I import them, using the "General" menu, "File System", but there's an issue with the result: apparently the ABL UI Design perspective (which shows the window), shrinks the window instead of keeping the actual size. As a result, I get overlapping widgets, which is really ugly.

In order to test this, I created a "full_screen.w" window (which looks exactly as the name says), but when importing it, it gets shrinked as mentioned.

Is there a way to prevent that shrinking?

**Extra question:** is there a StackOverflow tag for PDSOE?

**Edit after first answer**
The full_screen.w window has following definition, I have no idea of the unit this is based upon. However my progress.ini contained default fonts of size 12 instead of 8, modifying those values did not affect the appearance of the window, so apparently the window size is not based on character size. On what else can it be based?

Hereby the definition of the window:

```
/* *************************  Create Window  ************************** */

&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _CREATE-WINDOW
IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U THEN
  CREATE WINDOW C-Win ASSIGN
         ...
         HEIGHT             = 28.55
         WIDTH              = 228
         ...
         .
ELSE {&WINDOW-NAME} = CURRENT-WINDOW.
/* END WINDOW DEFINITION                                                */
&ANALYZE-RESUME
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't think there is already a tag for PDSOE. But with > 8000 reputation, you can create tags. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: That behavior sounds buggy ... haven't used PDSOE for AppBuilder a lot - but I would log this with Progress Tech support.

Comment: @Dominique Since your window is created with ``height`` and ``width`` and not with ``height-pixels`` and ``width-pixels`` it is being created with character units (see https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424919967860.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the size of your window defined?

If this is in character units, the size depends on the dimensions of your default font.

Fonts are defined in the `progress.ini` file or in the registry (`HKLM\software\psc\progress\<version>\`).

```
[Startup]
...
DefaultFont=MS Sans Serif, size=8
DefaultFixedFont=Courier New, size=8
...

[fonts]
;******************************************************************************
; THE DEFINITION OF FONT 0 THROUGH 7 IS PRIVATE TO THE PROGRESS ADE.  
; MODIFYING FONTS 0 THROUGH 7 MAY PREVENT THE PROGRESS ADE FROM RUNNING.
; The following fonts definitions correspond to the ADE standards.
;       ?  - DefaultFont from Startup Section
;       0  - DefaultFixedFont from Startup Section (1 char per PPU)  
;       1  - Proportional System Font
;       2  - Editor Font for 4GL program entry
;       3  - TTY Simulator (should be fixed)
;       4  - Dynamically-sized widgets, eg status-line, selection-list
;       5  - Static widgets, eg. combo-boxes
;       6  - Dynamic, bold (TranMan2)
;       7  - Reserved
font0=Courier New, size=8
font1=MS Sans Serif, size=8
font2=Courier New, size=8
font3=Courier New, size=8
font4=MS Sans Serif, size=8
font5=MS Sans Serif, size=10
font6=MS Sans Serif, size=8, bold
font7=MS Sans Serif, size=8
...
```

If your AppBuilder environment is using a different progress.ini or registry key for its fonts than your PDSOE run-time, then I would guess that what you are seeing is expected behaviour.

Comment: I've edited my question, answering your question. How can I know if the window is defined on character units or other? (And in case of other, which unit?)

Comment: Maybe another question: meanwhile I've discovered that the size of a window in appBuilder depends on `DefaultFont` or `DefaultFixedFont` in progress.ini, but the registry does not contain such key (only numbered fonts, like `font1`, `font2`, ...). What are the registry equivalents of those two progress.ini parameters?

Comment: @Dominique The entire ini file is mapped to the registry, the fonts in the [fonts] section are in \fonts, the DefaultFont and DefaultFixedFont are in the [startup] section, so can be found in \startup.